# How to disable the hints from autocomplete in Eclim?

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclim

When I use the autocomplete of Eclim in vim, it shows a hint window at the top of my vim.
How can I disable it, or better, make it disappear automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean the *preview window* showing details about the current completion item. Use

```
:set completeopt-=preview
```

to turn this off.